# Múltiplas janelas MDI em Web, similar Windows Forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Quero trabalhar com múltiplas janelas independentes no ambiante web com JavaScript, jQuery e etc. Similar a utilização de MDI no Windows Forms.

Sei que dá para fazer esse ambiente no Silverlight, mas quero fazer isso com linguagem de browser, e essas janelas irão se abrir à partir de uma chamada do servidor via SignalR, similar a um chat.